# VBScript to assign variables from XML nodes

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript

I am trying to write a simple VBScript that looks into an XML file, pulls out two attributes, adds them, and the result to an output file.  So far I have been able to load the XML input file using:

```
Option Explicit
Set objDoc = CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument")
objDoc.Load "C:\_STATS_SCRIPTS\STATS_HOME.xml"
```

Then I created and initialized variables like this:

```
Dim fumlost
Dim intercept
Dim turnovers
fumlost="0"
intercept="0"
turnovers="0"
```

Here is what my XML looks like (truncated after the totals subtree):

```
<fbgame source="Tas Football" version="4.16.01" generated="9/3/2014">
    <venue gameid="01UA-WVU" visid="WVU" homeid="UA" visname="West Virginia" homename="Alabama" date="8/30/2014" location="Atlanta, Georgia" stadium="Georgia Dome" start="3:36" end="7:05" neutralgame="Y" duration="3:29" attend="70502" temp="" wind="" weather="Indoor">
        <officials ref="David Epperly" ump="Mike Webster" line="Steve Clein" lj="Rod Pearson" bj="Pat Ryan" fj="Mike Culler" sj="Eddie Bonet"></officials>
        <notes>
            <note text="Replay: Dan Post"></note>
        </notes>
        <rules qtrs="4" mins="15" downs="4" yds="10" kospot="35" tbspot="20" kotbspot="25" patspot="3" safspot="20" td="6" fg="3" pat="1" patx="2" saf="2" defpat="2" rouge="1" field="100" toh="3" sackrush="Y" fgaplay="Y" netpunttb="Y"></rules>
    </venue>
    <team vh="H" code="8" id="UA" name="Alabama" record="1-0" abb="A">
        <linescore prds="4" line="3,17,10,3" score="33">
            <lineprd prd="1" score="3"></lineprd>
            <lineprd prd="2" score="17"></lineprd>
            <lineprd prd="3" score="10"></lineprd>
            <lineprd prd="4" score="3"></lineprd>
        </linescore>
        <totals totoff_plays="82" totoff_yards="538" totoff_avg="6.6">
            <firstdowns no="30" rush="13" pass="14" penalty="3"></firstdowns>
            <penalties no="7" yds="49"></penalties>
            <conversions thirdconv="9" thirdatt="15" fourthconv="0" fourthatt="1"></conversions>
            <fumbles no="0" lost="0"></fumbles>
            <misc yds="0" top="37:47" ona="0" onm="0" ptsto="0"></misc>
            <redzone att="4" scores="4" points="24" tdrush="3" tdpass="0" fgmade="1" endfga="0" enddowns="0" endint="0" endfumb="0" endhalf="0" endgame="0"></redzone>
            <rush att="49" yds="288" gain="294" loss="6" td="3" long="26"></rush>
            <pass comp="24" att="33" int="1" yds="250" td="0" long="38" sacks="0" sackyds="0"></pass>
            <rcv no="24" yds="250" td="0" long="38"></rcv>
            <punt no="2" yds="101" long="62" blkd="0" tb="0" fc="1" plus50="1" inside20="1" avg="50.5"></punt>
            <ko no="7" yds="453" ob="0" tb="3"></ko>
            <fg made="4" att="4" long="47" blkd="0"></fg>
            <pat kickatt="3" kickmade="3"></pat>
            <defense tackua="34" tacka="38" tot_tack="72" tflua="6" tfla="0" tflyds="30" sacks="3" sackyds="25" brup="3"></defense>
            <kr no="4" yds="99" td="0" long="26"></kr>
            <pr no="1" yds="-1" td="0" long="0"></pr>
            <scoring td="3" fg="4" patkick="3"></scoring>
        </totals>
```

What I need to do next is assign /fbgame/team/totals/fumbles@lost to my fumbles variable,  assign /fbgame/team/totals/pass@int to my intercept variable, and then add the two together to make turnovers, then output.  I think I can handle the summing of variables and outputting a file, but I'm lost on how to get the XML attribute assigned to my variables.  Earlier I successfully made a script that uses sXPath to split visiting team and home team out of my main input file, but I am currently unable to use what I learned there to get this task done!

I am very appreciative of any help that comes my way, as I am a n00b scripter and in a little over my head!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about using XPath in VBScript, but following XPath works for me:

```
string(//fbgame/team/totals/fumbles/@lost)
```

Result: 0

```
string(//fbgame/team/totals/pass/@int)
```

Result: 1

Maybe this works for your approach or you can adjust it further.

In case you'd need the whole node and not only the value, following XPath

```
//fbgame/team/totals/fumbles[@lost]
```

results in

```
 <fumbles no="0" lost="0" />
```

For providing completeness - depending on the query, `//fbgame` could be `/fbgame`. I just adjusted your XML-part to be valid for parsing and let the XPath match every `fbgame` (as the example only contains one game).

In case question wasn't about XPath expression but about how to get XPath values in VBScript, this should do it (at least getting the value, guess you would store the values in variables for doing the math later on):

```
For Each a In objDoc.selectNodes ("//fbgame/team/totals/fumbles/@lost")
 Wscript.Echo a.text
Next

For Each b In objDoc.selectNodes ("//fbgame/team/totals/pass/@int")
 Wscript.Echo b.text
Next
```

Comment: don't mind about the formatting, guess I get it ;) prob is to judge the result without knowing the XML, but wouldn't CInt(a) for a as string value 01 format to integer 1..? Hope that's no misunderstanding, just think that's the problem right now. Or can you already add up the results?

Comment: I can't add the two variables.  I think it's just putting them next to each other when I do "turnovers = intercept + fumlost"

Answer (score 0):

The code below is pulling values correctly, but when summing to 'turnovers' the returned output is "01" instead of just "1".  Is this correct??

```
Set colNodes=xmlDoc.selectNodes ("//fbgame/team/totals/pass/@int")

For Each objNode in colNodes
  intercept = objNode.text
  Wscript.Echo intercept 
Next

Set colNodes=xmlDoc.selectNodes ("//fbgame/team/totals/fumbles/@lost")

For Each objNode in colNodes
  fumlost = objNode.text
  Wscript.Echo fumlost
Next

turnovers = fumlost + intercept

Wscript.Echo turnovers
```

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say I need to convert the variables to integers.  I'm now looking for how to do that...

Comment: just have a look at my recent comment below, maybe that's it (in case it's CInt()

Comment: next thing is - guessing here: you already have two variables; just found for addition you'd have to set a 3rd, like: Dim Var3 - and then  Var3 = Var1 + Var2 for getting the result in Var3; maybe you just have to dim intercept + fumlost first, too? e.g. like here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_variables.htm

Comment: turnovers = CInt(fumlost) + CInt(intercept)  '  BOOM '

Comment: glad to be of help, good luck + thx for the question; didn't knew about vbscript xpath before, so seen something new

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!  Couldn't have done this without stackoverflow!  Final working code:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xmlDoc.Async = "False"
xmlDoc.Load("STATS_HOME.xml")


Dim fumlost
Dim intercept
Dim turnovers
fumlost="0"
intercept="0"
turnovers="0"

Set colNodes=xmlDoc.selectNodes ("//fbgame/team/totals/pass/@int")

For Each objNode in colNodes
  intercept = objNode.text
Next

Set colNodes=xmlDoc.selectNodes ("//fbgame/team/totals/fumbles/@lost")

For Each objNode in colNodes
  fumlost = objNode.text
Next
turnovers = CInt(fumlost) + CInt(intercept)

Dim fso
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\_STATS_SCRIPTS\TO_HOME.txt", 2)
f.Writeline turnovers
```